# Copying and pasting visible cells only

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a column of visible cells and paste to the next column over.

I can't find a macro that works. I had one going, but it only copies some numbers.

Here is the code

```
Sub TryMe()
Sheet1.Range("A1:A100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
  Destination:=Range("A1").Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
End Sub
```

This image is before I run the macro. Notice the rows that are hidden. I need these numbers to copy to the next column.
[image]

This image is after I run the macro. I don't understand why only some of the numbers are copying. The hidden rows contain the numbers 3 and 6. Why are they in the outcome, but not the visible numbers? I need to copy what is seen.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it that way even if you manually do it.
You will have to loop to get what you want. So give this a try.

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Sheet1.Range("A1:A100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Len(c) <> 0 Then c.Offset(0, 1) = c
Next
```

The odd thing about your result is why does it copy the values in reverse order.
I can understand if it copies all the visible cells at B1 onwards, but not the reversal of values.
Anyways, try above first if it gets you going.

Comment: I'm not sure why they were reversed either. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you have the output in reverse order, but for me your code works:

```
Sub TryMe()

    '1. some visible values in col A will be will be hidden in col B by hidden rows

    Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Range("A1").Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)

    '2. all visible values in col A will be will be visible bellow

    Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Range("A11").Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code guys! Works like a charm :)

```
Sub PasteToFilteredCells()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim n As Integer
n = 0
Dim x As Integer
Dim c As Integer
c = 0

xTitleId = "Paste Buddy"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Copy Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Paste Range:", xTitleId, Type:=8)
x = InputRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count   

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False    

For Each rng1 In InputRng
 If rng1.EntireRow.RowHeight > 0 Then
    rng1.Copy
    c = c + 1
 Else
    GoTo NextIte
 End If    
    Do While (c < (x + 1))            
     If (OutRng.Offset(n, 0).EntireRow.RowHeight > 0) Then      
      OutRng.Offset(n, 0).PasteSpecial
      n = n + 1
      GoTo NextIte        
     Else
      n = n + 1
     End If       
    Loop        
NextIte:
Next rng1

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```